# Requisição sem @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, json, jersey

Estou fazendo um cadastro simples de usuários com Java e AngularJS.

Minha requisição no javascript está assim:

```
$http({
    url: "rest/user/register",
    method: "POST",
    data: $scope.newUser
});
```

No java, eu tenho um metodo que recebe os dados em um POJO.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@POST
@Path("/register")
public String register(UserPojo userPojo){  
    return "teste";
}
```

O problema que estou enfrentando, é que na declaração do meu `UserPojo`, eu estou sendo obrigado a colocar a anotação `@XmlRootElement` para que funcione normalmente.

Se eu tiro a anotação, ocorre os seguintes erros:

```
GRAVE: A message body reader for Java class br.com.taskmanagement.pojo.UserPojo, 
and Java type class br.com.taskmanagement.pojo.UserPojo, 
and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.

The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json; charset=UTF-8 ->
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer sem `@XmlRootElement`, pois não estou enviando nada com XML.

Comment: Tá usando alguma lib de Json? Ex: `jersey-media-json-jackson`

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Estou usando jersey-json.jar

Comment: Tenta usar essa pra testar se o erro some: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.25

Comment: Não conheço a jersey-json, mas talvez seja necessário usar a anotação @XmlRootElement com ela.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Tentei com a lib que você comentou, mas também não deu certo :(

Comment: Você usa Maven? Se sim pode adicionar suas dependências?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Não estou usando Maven, tudo na mão.

Comment: Entendi, veja se te ajuda. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179737/jersey-json-media-type-application-json-was-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL/DR**: Mantenha as anotações do JAXB se você não tiver nenhum motivo maior para sair do padrão. Se você realmente precisar de algo específico habilite o Jackson.

Em versões atuais do Jersey a [forma padrão](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json) para trabalhar com JSON é usando [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy). Também por padrão as distribuições atuais utilizam anotações do [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) (como o `@XmlRootElement`) tanto para XML quanto para JSON.

Enquanto o JAXB foi originalmente projetado para trabalhar com XML (eis o motivo das anotações serem específicas para XML), não há nada errado em usar anotações do JAXB para trabalhar com JSON. A grande vantagem de trabalhar com JAXB, além de te poupar o trabalho de modificar as configurações do Jersey, é que todo seu mapeamento pode ser reaproveitado no futuro caso sua aplicação um dia precise de suporte para XML.

Se o JAXB realmente não atende as necessidadas da sua aplicação também é possível usar o Jackson diretamente. Dentre outras coisas o Jackson consegue trabalhar com POJOs não anotados. Existem alguns *corner cases* em que o Jackson pode valer a pena, por exemplo quando você precisa de [configurações finas](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/JacksonFeatures) não disponíveis no MOXy ao serializar / deserializar JSON.

Para habilitar o suporte ao Jackson são necessárias duas coisas:

1. Sua aplicação precisa referenciar as dependências corretas para fazer o Jersey trabalhar com o Jackson (veja [as configurações do Maven](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) ou [a lista de jars necessários](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.25/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) para fazer o Jersey 2.25 trabalhar com o Jackson 2.8.4).
2. É necessário configurar o Jersey para usar o Jackson

   ```
   final Application application = new ResourceConfig()
       .packages("com.minhaempresa.meuprojeto.meuspojos")
       .register(JacksonFeature.class); // habilita o Jackson
   ```

Para mais detalhes veja [a documentação sobre uso de Jackson com o Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)

Com essa configuração o Jersey passa a utilizar o  [`ObjectMapper`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding) do Jackson para serializar e deserializar POJOs. O Jackson é capaz de serializar POJOs sem que os mesmos estejam marcados com nenhuma anotação, porém suporta [anotações próprias](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) bem como [anotações JAXB](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations) quando essas são necessárias.

Veja [Jackson JAX-RS JSON Provider Example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/json-jackson) no repositório Git do Jersey para um exemplo completo com recursos que expõe POJOs não anotados, bem como anotados com o Jackson e com JAXB.